# Populating GridView, dynamically templating the edit fields, saving to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, datetimepicker

Alright, I am going to try and be as thorough as possible. I have gone through several (many) tutorials before resorting to posting here if anyone is wondering /=

I have several tables - one contains text/stored-procedure-name pairs which will populate a dropdown menu on the front end (Web Form). The other tables are accessed via the stored procedures. The idea is that I want to be able to be able to control from the back-end which fields are viewable/editable to the user on the front end. I also would like to be able to add / remove stored-procedures to retrieve data without having to mess with the front end.

The user can select from the drop down, and based on the selection a stored-procedure will be executed and then populate the gridview. No problems so far.

Now, ideally, the user will be able to edit the data presented in the gridview. This is easy enough, until we start getting fancy (i.e. overriding the default textbox controls that get generated). For example, when the user presses "edit" in the GridView row, and a record has the datatype "DateTime", I want some sort of calendar/clock to pop up and allow the user to pick the date and time, and then update it back into the database.

I've been running into roadblocks at this point. I've followed the tutorial on dynamically generating editable gridviews (http://aspalliance.com/1125_Dynamically_Templated_GridView_with_Edit_Delete_and_Insert_Options.1), but it does not work with what I am trying to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and I hope I have explained this with enough depth!

Code:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.setData();
}

public void setData()
{

    //Establishing the SQL Connection
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnString"].ConnectionString
        ))
    {

        //string query;
        SqlCommand SqlCommand;
        SqlDataReader reader;

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        //Open the connection to db
        conn.Open();

        //Generating the query to fetch the contact details
        //query = "SELECT * FROM " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + ";";

        SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, conn);
        //execute the query
        reader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        //Assign the results 
        GridView1.DataSource = reader;

        //Bind the data
        GridView1.DataBind();

        conn.Close();
    } }
```

The issue is that when this gets triggered:

```
  protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    this.setData();
}
```

All of the editable fields default to text boxes. I have been unable to get them to format according to datatype. Again, as an example, if the datatype is DateTime, a calendar should pop up and let user select date/time.

I know that there is a way to do it using  except this is for statically generated gridviews. This gridview is dynamic and its contents depend on procedures executed from the backend, so I can't hardcode the edit formats into the front end.

Comment: Your problem is not so clear!! Is the problem on how to use Calendar in GridView? Did you read [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_calenders.htm)? What do you mean by "dynamically generating editable GridViews"?

Comment: Show an example of what you tried when you say, "until we start getting fancy"  what did you do specifically that is not working?

Comment: When the user clicks the edit button in the gridview, I want each record to be templated dynamically according to its datatype. If the record is of the datatype DateTime, then the control for editing the record should be a calendar of some sort.

Comment: Welcome to SO: [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Anthony this comment area is not for clarifying what you tried.  it's for users to ask for more information from you, which you respond by editing your original post...in this case with code samples of what you've tried.

Comment: you can use `<EditItemTemplate>` for each field you need an Edit and define your own control.  I'm still unsure what issue you are facing...Please post some code and explain where you are struck!!